# I am trying to re-run a script that was working perfectly fine but is not anymore

Tags: r, error-handling

I ran the below code and have been getting this error.

code I ran -

```
headers <- read.csv(file.choose(), skip = 1, header = F, nrows = 1, as.is = T)

D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [100] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [200] is turned on
D_Lib: debug printing for files [.*] and level [300] is turned on
Error in header + nrows : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this. I donot have a programming background and I am a beginner in R.

Thanks,

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read in only 1 row of data, but also skipping the first row which implies you are not importing any rows.

Comment: @SteveM Incorrect: `skip=` controls how many rows are skipped, default to zero; `nrows` controls how many rows are read after the appropriate number of rows (if any) are skipped. With `(skip=1,nrows=1)`, it reads the second line of the file.

Comment: @r2evans.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is likely related to `file.choose()` using the native file dialog, and some ViewFinity (now CyberArk) "security" product installed. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/32056783/, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43979346/, https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41b6ab50-04ae-4353-93c1-a0984485a8fb/

Answer (score 0):

This bug is confirmed by my IT department to be a CyberArk Endpoint Project Manager bug.  This bug was fixed in EPM SaaS version 22.4 (released in April 2022).  The On-Prem version has not been fixed to my knowledge.